# How to get event of changing current keyboard layout in Unix?

Tags: c++, qt, unix, x11

I searched simple solution, but could not find.

I need getting event of changing system keyboard layout for setting this in my application.

`QApplication::keyboardInputLocale()` is not suitable, because I need to catch system layout, not the application.

Xkblib also is not suitable, because I use Qt project and this library can lead to crashes (`QEvent`, `QTimer`).

Comment: Try catching `XkbStateNotify` events.

Comment: Thanks, but using xkblib is very very difficult for me. I searching a simple solution. And I use the qt project. Therefore, this library can lead to crashes (QEvent, QTimer).

Answer (score 0):

X sends a MapNotifyEvent (not to be confused with KeymapNotify) when the key mapping is changed (tested with xmodmap, but should work for other methods as well). I don't know if you can get at raw X events under Qt, but if you can, I think that's the event to look for.